# return the text value of tags and append a line break to each tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So if I call this function:

```
$("#item").text()
```

on this HTML code:

```
<div id="item">
<pre><span class="cm-tag">&lt;html&gt;</span></pre><pre><span class="cm-tab">    </span>asdf</pre><pre><span class="cm-tag">&lt;/html&gt;</span></pre>
</div>
```

it returns:

```
'<html>    asdf</html>'
```

and i want it to return:

```
'<html>
    asdf
</html>'
```

basically i need a new line after each `<pre>` tag... how would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, get the text of each pre and join them with new lines:

```
var text = $("#item pre").map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join('\n');
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uGGFe/

Comment: like i don't want them to be joined together by '\n's i want them to be joined as if you were pressing enter in the javascript variable... if that makes sense

Comment: this returns: "<html>    asdf</html>"

Comment: @maxhud `\n` is called the [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages) character and can be used in many languages include c, javascript, python and many others as a representation of "as if you were pressing enter". Edited my answer with a link to a jsfiddle with the working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for you:

```
var clone = $("#item").clone(); //create a clone we can manipulate
clone.find('pre').after('\n');  //stick new lines in after <pre> tags
alert(clone.text());            //behold the alert glory
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SrV9c/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = '';
$("#item pre").map(function(i, el) {
    return $(el).text().replace(/\s/g, '')
}).each(function(i, val) {
    if (i == 0) 
        text += val.concat('\n\t');
    else
        text += val.concat('\n');
});
```

​
**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/thesystemrestart/XQwB3/15/)**

Comment: @maxhud please check my answer and demo

Answer (score 0):

because jQuery search  match htmlElement use regular expression, when  regular expression match content first delete  "\r\n", so you see the content not have "\r\n"

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.